# why react should usually be a prod dependency and not dev-dependency

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dependencies

Sorry if I'm missing some obvious thing, but I can't seem to understand why react (or react-dom) should be a dependency and not dev-dependency on most projects..
Usually the src is written in es6 and stored in /src or /client for example, and when someone want to build the project for prod he will create /build or /dist where the finalize bundle.js will seat (using webpack and such). from there (at prod) it simply a web server which serve regular js (the bundle) and html file.

Do I miss somthing?

I dont understand why will I want react on the prod (unless going for SSR of course)..

Thank you very much!

Comment: you will have your react components as createElement functions which react only understands. React still internally creates DOM for you and is required to run

Answer (score 19):

`dependencies` are required to `run`, `devDependencies` only to `develop`, e.g.: unit tests, Coffeescript to Javascript transpilation, minification, ...

`React` is a dependency because it is included in the final build.

In case of a React App, all your JSX is converted to a syntax similar to `React.createElement` and hence you would require your App to have React during run time as well. Similary methods like `setState` and `lifecyle functions` are all executed during run-time.

As a matter of fact react is a library that has exposed some methods and APIs to access and manipulate DOM.

Consider this similar to `jquery` or `express` where you add it in the production build because they are being used during run time.

When creating a react app, things like `babel`, `webpack` etc which are only used to create a bundle would be dev-dependencies as once the packaged bundle is generated it need not be generated during run time of application

Comment: This is incorrect, please see the answer from @eastern_muffin. React is bundled in the final output from Webpack and is only listed under "dependencies" for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same question and found [this article](https://jsramblings.com/do-dependencies-devdependencies-matter-when-using-webpack/) that explains it well.

To summarize, it shouldn't matter where you put the react dependencies since Webpack will bundle them into a self-contained file and the code will run fine in either case. However, separating development and production dependencies allows for a better communication to other developers for the purpose of these dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is what I was looking for. I have seen code putting ReactJs in devDependencies because webpack already packed React in the result. Nice to know it is mainly used for documentations.

Answer (score 2):

A `dependency` is something that is imported in the src/ or client/ module like you mentioned. The code that you run depends on it and hence is required in the production bundle.

If it were something like `Babel` it could be a devDependency because:

1. It is not imported in source code.
2. It is a transpiler and works on code in compile time

But that is not the case with React. Functions like `setState` or lifecycle hooks are being executed in run time, meaning the library has to be present during run time.

React could very well be listed as a peer dependency is some of the popuar libraries. This is because we assume that all projects that are going to use this library are going to have `React` installed. Like consider the case of `react-bootstrap`. It can only be run in react projects, so we include react as peer dependency reducing the overhead of installing it.

If you need a framework that would disappear in compile time, take a look at [Svelte](https://svelte.technology/).

Comment: But isn't writing: import react from 'react' means that webpack will import the whole react library into the bundle?

Comment: Yes, it means `React` will be imported. `dependencies` are what is imported into the code this way.

Comment: If we are ignoring things importing into `webpack`, we would not have any dependencies.

Comment: Exactly..Webpack does all the dependencies for me (on dev), so why should I want to "reinstall" react when I hit npm install on my prod server. As I get it, when I will npm install on prod I need only express and whichever dependencies my server uses (API for example)

Comment: When you have a bundle file, you need only the bundle. You don't need `dependencies` or `devDependencies`. You shouldn't do `npm install` at all

Comment: Thanks, so I should include react in dependencies only if doing server side rendering?

Comment: You are including dependencies in package.json for a dev environment or for a library. Not so that we can install them on the server.

Comment: What do you mean for a library? But overall I think I got the point, I thought that dev dependencies are for the development server and regular dependencies are just what you need to run the prod server.

Comment: If you are authoring a library, then the person doing `npm install library-name` installs what is listed in dependencies.