# Cannot find module '@storybook/react' or its corresponding type declarations. On Heroku

Tags: reactjs, typescript, heroku, storybook, react-typescript

I'm having in issue when my app gets deployed on heroku with the next message.

[image]

My app is running on typescript/react that I want to deploy to Heroku. I am using `storybook/react` in my application.

This is my `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

The structure of my project is:

```
- public
- src
   - components
     - (In here I have all the imports to storybook)
  - connectors
  - hooks
  - layout
  - state
  - theme
  - utils
```

I have storybook/react in `devDependencies`:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.1",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.1",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.1",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.3.1",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.6",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.3.8",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "create-react-component-folder": "^0.3.7",
    "husky": "^7.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "yargs": "^17.0.1"
  }
```

I also have this too in my dependencies object in package.json:

```
"@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
"@types/react": "^17.0.11",
"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.8",
```

I don't know what I have wrong. The worst thing is that if I run the app locally it works but on Heroku it just breaks. Any idea of that this could be? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just checked [Heroku's Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#build-behavior) and says that `devDependencies` are stripped out before deployment. I think it's because the `devDependencies` are only used to build and if I remember correctly Storybook is used at runtime not compilation. So, just moving it from `devDependencies`, to `dependencies` should do the trick.

```
 {
  "dependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.1",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.1",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.1",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.3.1",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.6",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.3.8",
  }
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861868/why-react-should-usually-be-a-prod-dependency-and-not-dev-dependency) discusses whether React is a `devDependency` or `dependency`. Maybe it will help :)