# Should react and react-dom be devDependecies?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json, react-dom

I use webpack to bundle all files for production on the web. Since no code runs on node during production, thus no package being `require`d in production, should all dependencies be development only?

I don't want an answer based on opinions or best practices or intended usage, I simply want what makes sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why react should usually be a prod dependency and not dev-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861868/why-react-should-usually-be-a-prod-dependency-and-not-dev-dependency)

Comment: @Reborn yes, yes it does -- The only answer I will get is "based on opinions or best practices or intended usage", thus giving me the answer I **asked** for -- they should be put in devDependecies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only answer you will get to this question will be "based on opinions or best practices or intended usage". For those who were not looking for such answers, the answer is:

If there is no backend service in the **same** project where you are making the frontend app via a bundler, then put everything in devDependecies; otherwise only put the packages you will `require` in some node.js related code in dependencies.