# Does Webpack include all dependent node modules along with the created bundle for production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

We all know that when we hit the npm run build, the react scripts uses the Webpack and creates a bundle going through all the dependency graph (follow the imports) and creates a bundle.js and places it inside dist/build folder which is used for production. I recently read that even *React is a devDependency* (?) because once the bundle has been created there’s no need of react (basically no need of node_modules) at production because the final bundle is a mix of js and css files which the browser can understand. Here are my questions.

**1) Please let me know if the above statement about React being a devDependency is correct or not?**

**2) Since we have a lot of dependent node modules when we install a node package. Is Webpack going to bundle all these node modules as well into the final bundle.js? If so, wouldn’t it be a very large bundle? How does this work?**

Comment: you could find this discussion useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861868/why-react-should-usually-be-a-prod-dependency-and-not-dev-dependency#:~:text=dependencies%20are%20required%20to%20run,included%20in%20the%20final%20build.

Comment: Thanks for this link, it helped me to find the answer for the first question.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, React is a dev dependency in a bundled app, because you don't need it in production unless you also do server side rendering. Consider  a case where you have a frontend app with an express server. You bundle the app using webpack and deploy it as static JS/CSS asset, but you express server no longer needs it as you are not doing SSR. So for deploying the server, you can prune dev dependencies, keep around only what's needed by the server and keep the server smaller.

Comment: What I understood is, whether it is a dev dependency or just a dependency in package.json, these are segregated for documentation purpose, all packages will be installed on npm install, and when doing npm build, the dependencies that are imported will be bundled in the bundle.js (example, react) and dependencies that are not used to run the app itself (webpack, babel) will not be bundled with the app.

Comment: And coming back to my 2nd question, if dependencies inside node modules are bundled as it is or may be added as a cdn link inside the bundle.js (for example, we have cdn links for react which can be used to implement react based apps in plain static js files, like any other library)

Comment: You can do `npm install --only=prod` when eg. building a docker image for your express server to skip dev dependencies. So while `npm install` installs all, you have options. There is no difference for Webpack/Babel with default setup, but you can differentiate using `externals` configuration, for example.